# Intersection of Parametric Equation of a Line with the Standard Equation of an Ellipse

Tags: geometry, parametric

I am trying to derive an equation that yields the values of λ at the intersection point between a ray and an ellipse. The solution should arrange in a second degree equation.

The equations I am using are
$$\vec{l}(λ)=\vec{p}+λ\vec{d}$$
$$\frac{(x-c_x)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-c_y)^2}{b^2}=1$$
where
$$\vec{p}=[p_x,p_y]$$
is the starting point of the line
$$\vec{d}=[d_x,d_y]$$
is the direction of the line
$$\vec{c}=[c_x,c_y]$$
is the centre of the ellipse.

Then I rearranged the equation to solve for x and y.
$$x=\pm\frac{a\sqrt{b^2-c_y^2+2c_yy-y^2}}{b}+c_x$$
$$y=\pm\frac{b\sqrt{a^2-c_x^2+2c_xx-x^2}}{a}+x_y$$
and substitude the x and y for the x and y equations for the line.

$$p_x+λd_x=\pm\frac{a\sqrt{b^2-c_y^2+2c_yy-y^2}}{b}+c_x$$
$$p_y+λd_y=\pm\frac{b\sqrt{a^2-c_x^2+2c_xx-x^2}}{a}+x_y$$
To get the following two equations find λ:
$$λ=\pm\frac{b\sqrt{a^2-c_y^2+2c_yy-y^2}+bc_x-bd_x}{ad_y}$$
$$λ=\pm\frac{a\sqrt{b^2-c_x^2+2c_xx-y^2}+ac_y-ad_y}{bd_x}$$

I am unsure if I am on the right track to solve for λ as I am currently missing values to substitute for x and y inside of the equations. It is also unclear how I am suppose to rearrange the equation to a quadratic form.

Comment: The process is *much* simpler than you're doing. ... The line equation tells you that $x=p_x+\lambda d_x$ and $y=p_y+\lambda d_y$. Use these to replace $x$ and $y$ in your ellipse equation, and you'll have a quadratic in $\lambda$.

Comment: Would the equation be simplifyable or would the number of terms be crazy? Around 2 for ^2, 4 for  and 7 constants?

Comment: It's moderately crazy. (A computer algebra system like *Mathematica* helps with the symbol-juggling.) Here's the quadratic (writing $t$ for $\lambda$ to save typing): $$\begin{align} 
0 &= t^2\left(a^2 d_y^2+b^2 d_x^2\right) \\
&+2t\left(a^2d_y(p_y - c_y)+b^2d_x(p_x-c_x)\right) \\
&+ a^2 (p_y-c_y)^2 +b^2(p_x-c_x)^2-a^2 b^2 \end{align}$$ The discriminant can be written $$4 a^2 b^2 \left(a^2 d_y^2 + b^2 d_x^2 - ((p_y-c_y) d_x - (p_x-c_x) d_y)^2\right)$$

Comment: If you write $(p_x,p_y) = (c_x,c_y)+p(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ and $(d_x,d_y)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, the quadratic becomes $$\begin{align}
0&= t^2\left(a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta\right)\\
&+2pt\left(a^2\sin\theta\sin\phi+b^2 \cos\theta\cos\phi\right) \\
&+ p^2\left(a^2\sin^2\phi+b^2\cos^2\phi\right)-a^2 b^2  
\end{align}$$ and the discriminant is $$4 a^2 b^2 (a^2 \sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta-p^2 \sin^2(\theta-\phi))$$